# Specifiying the Table in an OpenQuery SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the syntax that I need to run an insert on a linked server (mySQL is the Linked Server, MSSQL SSMS the host).

I've seen many examples but how do you specify the receiving table? (mySQL is the receiving server)

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (mySQL, 'SELECT name FROM MSSQL_Table')
VALUES ('name');
```

Comment: Have you read the doc? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms188427.aspx There are pretty clear examples there.

Answer (score 0):

The table and column specified in the SELECT part of the OPENQUERY statement will be used for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (mySQL, 'SELECT TargetColumn FROM mySQL_TargetTable')
VALUES ('name');
```

The example will insert the value 'name' into column TargetColumn of table mySQL_TargetTable at the mySQL linked server.

Comment: So it's necessary to have both databases/tables with identical names?